In Linux, if creating a TCP map with a port forwarder to a SOCKS5 proxy server, being them listening in different IPs, UDP associate doesn't work
In Linux, when I forward a TCP port with a port forwarder (such as socat) to a port of a local SOCKS5 proxy server, I can connect to the first using UDP (UDP) only if the port mapped with a port forwarder is listening in the same local IP.
UDP associate doesn't work if the port forwarder is listening in a different local IP other than the SOCKS5 server one.
Here the logs of the port forwarder and the SOCKS5 server:
$ socat -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:1080,bind=127.0.0.1,fork,reuseaddr TCP4:192.168.1.5:1080
2024/06/06 19:25:12 socat[942508] N listening on AF=2 127.0.0.1:1080
2024/06/06 19:25:14 socat[942508] N accepting connection from AF=2 127.0.0.1:35677 on AF=2 127.0.0.1:1080
2024/06/06 19:25:14 socat[942508] N forked off child process 942513
2024/06/06 19:25:14 socat[942508] N listening on AF=2 127.0.0.1:1080
2024/06/06 19:25:14 socat[942513] N opening connection to AF=2 192.168.1.5:1080
2024/06/06 19:25:14 socat[942513] N successfully connected from local address AF=2 192.168.1.5:58166
2024/06/06 19:25:14 socat[942513] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [6,6] and [5,5]
2024/06/06 19:25:14 socat[942513] N write(5, 0x60071a85f000, 3) completed
2024/06/06 19:25:14 socat[942513] N write(6, 0x60071a85f000, 2) completed
2024/06/06 19:25:14 socat[942513] N write(5, 0x60071a85f000, 22) completed
2024/06/06 19:25:14 socat[942513] N write(6, 0x60071a85f000, 10) completed
2024/06/06 19:25:14 socat[942513] N socket 2 (fd 5) is at EOF
2024/06/06 19:25:15 socat[942513] N exiting with status 0
2024/06/06 19:25:15 socat[942508] N childdied(): handling signal 17

$ socks -l -i192.168.1.5 -p1080
240606232323.474 1080 00000 - 192.168.1.5:1080 0.0.0.0:0 0 0 0 Accepting connections [942456/2509023040]
240606232342.207 1080 00465 - 192.168.1.5:50126 1.1.1.1:53 0 0 0 UDPMAP 1.1.1.1:53
240606232347.212 1080 00465 - 192.168.1.5:50138 1.1.1.1:53 0 0 0 UDPMAP 1.1.1.1:53
240606232446.977 1080 00465 - 192.168.1.5:36432 2606:4700:4700::1111:53 0 0 0 UDPMAP 2606:4700:4700::1111:53
240606232451.981 1080 00465 - 192.168.1.5:35354 2606:4700:4700::1111:53 0 0 0 UDPMAP 2606:4700:4700::1111:53

The SOCKS5 server receives the UDP connections, but it cannot send it back.
Here is the connection test (using Dante's socksify):
$ SOCKS_SERVER=127.0.0.1:1080 socksify nc -z -u 1.1.1.1 53 || echo 1
1
$ SOCKS_SERVER=192.168.1.5:1080 socksify nc -z -u 1.1.1.1 53 || echo 1
Connection to 1.1.1.1 53 port [udp/domain] succeeded!

Is there a way to correct this behavior?
